# I want on basis of entering EmpId in a text box all other text boxes present in form for that particular emp should be also filled

Tags: asp.net

I want when user enters the emp id automatically (on basis of that particular id filled by user)all other information of that particular employee should be filled in the form and should be kept disabled until the emp presses the edit button.

I have designed a registration form in which I have following text boxes and 3 buttons 
emp Id 
nationality
religion
gender

save button  edit button  clear button

I have already implemented the coding for save button and clear button. When user clicks on save button after filling the form the data gets stored in the database table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlDataReader dr;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SAKSHIKAUL-LT\SQLEXORESS1;Initial Catalog=registrationForm;Integrated Security=True";
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SAKSHIKAUL-LT\SQLEXORESS1;Initial Catalog=registrationForm;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        conn.Open();
        {
            string FetchData = "Select * from EmpDetails where EmpId=''";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(FetchData, conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
                Label1.Text = "";
        }

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text += dr[0].ToString() + " ";
            TextBox2.Text += dr[1].ToString() + " ";
            TextBox3.Text += dr[2].ToString() + " ";
            TextBox4.Text += dr[3].ToString() + " ";
            TextBox5.Text += dr[4].ToString() + " ";
            TextBox6.Text += dr[5].ToString() + " ";
            TextBox7.Text += dr[6].ToString() + " ";
            conn.Close();
            {

            }
        }
    }        

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into RegistrationTable" + "(EmpId,Nationality,Religion,Gender,Address,EmailId,Hobbies,MaritalStatus) values (@EmpId,@Nationality,@Religion,@Gender,@Address,@EmailId,@Hobbies,@MaritalStatus)", con);

        //string insertQuery = "insert into RegistrationTable(EmpId,Nationality,Religion,Gender,Address,EmailId,Hobbies,Maritalstatus)values (@EmpId,@Nationality,@Religion,@Gender,@Address,@EmailId,@MHobbies,@Maritalstatus)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", TextBox6.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobbies", TextBox7.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maritalstatus", TextBox8.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = "Registered Successfuly";


    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { cmd.CommandText = "update RegistrationTable set Nationality =' " + TextBox2.Text + "' where EmpId='" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd.CommandText = "update RegistrationTable set Religion =' " + TextBox3.Text + "' where EmpId='" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd.CommandText = "update RegistrationTable set Gender =' " + TextBox4.Text + "' where EmpId='" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd.CommandText = "update RegistrationTable set Address =' " + TextBox5.Text + "' where EmpId='" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd.CommandText = "update RegistrationTable set EmailId =' " + TextBox6.Text + "' where EmpId='" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd.CommandText = "update RegistrationTable set Hobbies =' " + TextBox7.Text + "' where EmpId='" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd.CommandText = "update RegistrationTable set MaritalStatus =' " + TextBox8.Text + "' where EmpId='" + TextBox1.Text + "' ";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Label1.Text = "Updated Successfuly";
        }





    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = ""; 
        TextBox2.Text = ""; 
        TextBox3.Text = ""; 
        TextBox4.Text = ""; 
        TextBox5.Text = ""; 
        TextBox6.Text = ""; 
        TextBox7.Text = ""; 
        TextBox8.Text = ""; 

        Label1.Text = "Clear All";
    }

    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Expected output-When user enters the EmpId all other text boxes present in the form should be filled automatically(from already existing database) and should be kept disabled until user clicks on edit button

actual result- user enters the emp id and he has to then fill all the text boxes. Its not getting updated automatically.when user clicks on save button the data get registered in a table and clear button is also clearing all ext boxes.